# implement mapping for MySQL year type in django

Tags: mysql, django, sqldatatypes

There is a [year](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html) data type in MySQL and there is no corresponding data field type in django ORM. Can I provide a custom field class to map data type for one specific RDBMS? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find following solution which satisfies my needs (`models.py`):

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldError

class YearField(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        if connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.mysql':
            return 'year'
        else:
            raise FieldError
```

and then use the column datatype in models:

```
class Band(models.Model):
    """Music band"""
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'band'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    active_since = YearField()
    active_until = YearField(null=True)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```